# Jquery Dialog box: ajax call is sent multiple times

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, dialog

I have a form:

```
    <div id="dialog" style="visibility:hidden" title="Add Name">
     <% form_tag :controller => 'trial', :action => 'create' do %>
      Name: <%= text_field_tag 'name', '', :size => 25 %> <br />
      <%= submit_tag 'Submit', :id => "_button" %>
     <% end %>
    </div>
```

This is a dialog box. The initialization is done as:

```
 $(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: {
    effect: "blind",
    duration: 1000
    },
    width: "420px",
    hide: {
      effect: "blind",
      duration: 1000
    }
  });
```

Now on form submit I have an ajaxSubmit.

```
$("#dialog").dialog("open");
  $("#dialog form").submit(function(){
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
      success: function (dataresult, textStatus, jqXHR, $form) {    
        $("#dialog").dialog('close');
      }
    })
    return false;       
  })
```

The problem is, first time we submit the form, it sends ajax call one time, but if we just close the dialog box without refreshing the whole page, it sends the ajax call twice and so on. I already tried doing `unbind` of the click event for the button. But, still it doesn't work. Any help?

Comment: looks like you are binding submit event each time but cannot spot it in code posted, missing some relevant part. Not as good but as simple solution, just unbind submit event each time: `$("#dialog form").off('submit').submit(function(){...});` Better would be to bind it only once...

Comment: can you create fiddle